# Count down using array of images Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So i'm trying to create a basic count down using my 3 images (3, 2, 1) but having a 2 second gap in between each go. I have a console log there to see if they even go through when i execute the script and they do. So now i just need to make a 2 second gap in between... that's were i get stuck. Help? The way i have it now is that it waits 2 seconds then launches the whole code and doesn't wait in between each.

```
var numImgCont = [];
numImgCont[0] = "./imgs/3.jpg";
numImgCont[1] = "./imgs/2.jpg";
numImgCont[2] = "./imgs/1.jpg";

apples = function(){

    setTimeout(
        function(){
            for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {  
            console.log(numImgCont[i])
            document.getElementById("imgcontainer").src =numImgCont[i]; 
        };

    }, 500);

}
```

Comment: try setInterval instead

Comment: Can you add what you've tried to jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Example (running `window.onload` or `onDOMReady`, or inline after the `imgcontainer` element):

```
var numImgCont = [];
numImgCont[0] = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
numImgCont[1] = "http://placehold.it/300x300";
numImgCont[2] = "http://placehold.it/400x400";

var apples = (function loop(){
    var container = document.getElementById("imgcontainer");

    if (numImgCont.length) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            container.src = numImgCont.shift();
            loop();
        }, 2000);
    }

    return loop;
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69RN5/1

Slightly different method:

```
var numImgCont = [];
numImgCont[0] = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
numImgCont[1] = "http://placehold.it/300x300";
numImgCont[2] = "http://placehold.it/400x400";

var apples = (function run(){
    var container = document.getElementById("imgcontainer");

    return (function loop(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (numImgCont.length) {
                container.src = numImgCont.shift();
                loop();
            }
        }, 2000);

        return loop;
    })();

})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69RN5/4

Comment: Thanks for these. They really help. Just bummed out because i didn't think about it doing it this way.
What i don't understand is the "if(numImgCont.Lenght)" does that mean 
"if (numImgCont is 3?).

Comment: `Array.prototype.length` gives the current number of items in the array. `Array.prototype.shift()` takes the first item off the list and returns it. Thus, checking the length property tells you how many items are left in the array, so it works until all items have been shifted off (and `numImgCont.length` gives `0`).

Comment: Any reason why it's skipping over the [2] array?

var numImgCont = [];
numImgCont[0] = "./imgs/3.jpg";
numImgCont[1] = "./imgs/2.jpg";
numImgCont[2] = "./imgs/1.jpg";
numImgCont[3] = "./imgs/ninja.jpg";

var countDown = function loop(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (numImgCont.length){
            document.getElementById("imgcontainer").src = numImgCont.shift();
            loop();
        };
    },2000);
    return loop;
};

Answer (score 0):

You can use IEFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) and `setTimeout`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/LSHLV/).

```
var container = document.getElementById('imgcontainer'),
    images = ['src1', 'src2', 'src3'];

(function show() {
    container.src = images.shift();
    images.length && setTimeout(show, 2000);    
}());
```